# Ensure only numeric value entered

Tags: shell-script

I have shell script for data entry. Same is made for various data entry which creates file and further for statement generation.i have a part as below where i want to ensure that entered value must be number e.g.130,1300,13500 or any thing but only number.currently i am doing this:

```
echo -e "Enter loan amount :\c"
read amount
case $amount in
[0-9]) echo $amount >>manual-entry ;;
*)echo " Entered value is not number" ;;
esac
```

This allowed only one number to enter.  My enter value can 1 to 99999999999 anything. How can i fix this

Comment: Should your script allow floating point numbers? (numbers with decimals)

Comment: negative numbers? hex numbers? scientific notation?

Comment: Yes may with decimal,no hex,scitific nos

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shell test to perform an integer comparison against itself:

```
read -rp 'Enter loan amount: ' amount
if [ "${amount:-0}" -eq "${amount:-1}" 2>/dev/null ]; then
  echo "$amount" >> manual-entry
else
  echo "Invalid input, number is expected" >&2
fi
```

We are comparing `${amount:-0}` to `${amount:-1}` to ensure this will still fail on `null` input.  Otherwise the `-eq` operator will error for a non-integer comparison.  If the input is an integer it will pass.

Note: this will not support floating point

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like this

```
typeset -i amount
read -rp 'Enter loan amount: ' amount
[[ "$amount" == 0 ]] && echo "enter a positive integer"
echo $amount >>manual-entry
```

This will produce an error on entering a floating point number. Entering a string will set amount to 0.

Comment: This would still execute `echo $amount >>manual-entry` no matter what the input is.  That may not be what OP is looking for

Comment: indeed, I'd rewrite as `if [[ "$amount" -gt 0 ]]; then echo "$amount" >> manual-entry; else echo "Echo a positive integer"; fi`, or possibly use an `until` loop rather than a single if/then test.

Comment: @Jesse_b This can be fixed by adding `&& exit 0` after the `echo`

Comment: @DougO'Neal: In this case it's likely fine but it's generally bad practice to chain more than one `&&` or `||` in a single list.  I would recommend an if construct as DopeGhoti suggested.